# Loading a unix executable file within ios app

Tags: ios, unix

I have a unix executable file that I need to run when the application is launched. Basically the file is a server using xml-rpc to communicate with the client. Does iOS allow execution of such files? This app is not going to be submitted to the app store so I'm not worried about that. I'm merely setting this up as a small testing project. I've tried posix_spawn but a simple ls command returns the error "Bad address." I tried this command with path to my file but got similar error.

```
char argv[] = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "ls", NULL};

int status = posix_spawn(&pid, argv[0], NULL, NULL, argv, environ);

if (status == 0) {
    printf("Child pid: %i\n", pid);
} else {
    printf("posix_spawn: %s\n", strerror(status));
}
```

Comment: Finally can you able to make use of unix executable file within iOS app ?

Answer (score 2):

iOS doesn't allow you to spawn new processes.

Comment: Thanks. I used execl() instead which isn't returning any error messages so digging further now to see if it actually ran the file successfully.

Comment: @ussd84 did it run successfully?

Comment: @ussd84 If it is returning anything, the `exec` call was **not** successful